# python not defined error function/argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, tkinter, interface

I am having a problem with an error message about tk not being defined?

How can I get around this, I thought I defined it. I was wondering if it was a problem with the `window = tk` but when I remove one and vice versa the define problem still occurs.

```
import tkinter
import os

window = tk()
window.title("Computer Science Revision")
window.geometry("1000x1000")
window.wm_iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
window.configure(background="#a1dbcd")

photo= tkinter.PhotoImage(file="ryu.gif")
w = tkinter.Label(image=photo)
w.pack()

creds = 'tempfile.temp'

def Signup():
    global pwordE
    global NameE
    global roots

    roots = Tk()
    roots.title('Signup')
    insturction = Label(roots, text= 'Please enter new Credentials\n')
    instruction.grid(row=0, column =0,sticky=W)

    nameL =  Label(roots, text='New Username: ')
    pwordL =  Label(roots, text='New Password: ')
    nameL.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    pword.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
    nameE = Entry(roots)
    pwordE = Entry(roots, show='*')
    nameL.grid(row=1, column=1)
    pwordE.grid(row=2, column=1)

    signupButton = Button(roots, text='Signup', command=FSSignup)
    signupButton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)
    roots.mainloop()
```

Comment: `import tkinter ; import os ; window = tk()` Where does anything named `tk` being defined?

Comment: You didn't import the name `tk`. You only imported the module `tkinter`. Besides, the class is called `Tk` (uppercase `T`). If you are importing just the module, use `window = tkinter.Tk()`.

Comment: As always, carefully review the documentation, this is covered in the [module introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules).

Comment: still facing problems of "GlobalEL" not being defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit namespace messed up. Some parts of your code follows the format `from tkinter import *` provides. While some parts followed the format `import tkinter`. You *can* do both, but it's not preferred. 
Many people like to use import `tkinter as tk` since it's easy to type and use.

Your error is that you used `tk()` which isn't a thing. `tkinter.Tk()` is probably what you meant.

And you should change all `Label` to `tkinter.Label` and `Entry` to `tkinter.Entry` inside your `Signup` function, to fit your `import tkinter` code. The place where you copied from most likely had `from tkinter import *` in the top.

Comment: Did my answer provided you a better understanding? If so, feel free to accept my answer and/or upvote. But if not, what else regarding your question do you need better understanding with?

Comment: Now receiving an error comment; global name e is not defined in instruction.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)

Comment: it's tk.E just like everything else

Comment: There's so much way of doing things, you can also include in the top `from tkinter.constants import *` that way you wouldn't have to change the constants. ie. E, W

Comment: Another error if you could help please.... Error message:line 84, in CheckLogin uname = data[0].rstrip() IndexError: list index out of range CODE : def CheckLogin(): with open(creds) as f: data = f.readlines() uname = data[0].rstrip() pword = data[1].rstrip(

Comment: im also looking to add the window part of my code into the main part of my code so it all opens in one window... where should I put this?

Comment: try checking to see what *is* in `data` first by doing `print(data)`. And do you mind editing your original question to include the details or write a new question. It's quite impossible to read from the comments.

Comment: is there any other way I can contact you?

Comment: i have further problems with my code... and it would be much easier than opening a new question each time

Comment: I'll try helping you this time, just edit your question and add your new question on to it, but don't remove your old question. But after this, you will need to ask a new question, sorry but that's how SO operates

Comment: "globalEL" is not defined still